# C++ - Force std::fstream to read from disk

Tags: c++, caching, fstream

I am developing an application similar to a database with its own system for managing memory and that persists data by writing it into a file on disk.

In order to read/write from this file I am using a std::fstream. However, due to testing purposes, I would like to force it to read/write directly from disk instead of the disk cache. Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure C++ even knows what a disk is...

Comment: I agree in that probably C++ has no way to do so. But maybe some Linux command...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to purge disk I/O caches on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9551838/how-to-purge-disk-i-o-caches-on-linux)

Comment: I am already running `sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sda && hdparm -F /dev/sda` before testing as you suggest. This flushes disk cache but does not disable it, so the program eventually starts hitting the cache again.

Comment: You may also want to check out https://superuser.com/questions/242928/disable-linux-read-and-write-file-cache-on-partition

Comment: Thanks! The pagecache-management.sh tool is what I was looking for.